# Properly format array for jQuery display

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I'm currently working on a blog type page with a comment area, this is a personal learning adventure and I would appreciate detailed explanations to solidify the learning. I currently have everything structured in an MVC pattern for PHP using CodeIgniter, and my JavaScript code is also formatted in a similar fashion.

**EDIT:** I've added the output of the array from the build_array() function from PHP. I feel that is the root cause of my issue, if I could rework the array to not feed each comment the entire blog data it would allow me to achieve what I desire.

I appreciate all of the comments and I may not know all that you ask so please be patient with me, I'm slow. (:

I can't figure out how to get the data to be displayed properly, currently it outputs:

```
Blog Post Two
Blog Post Two Comment

Blog Post Two
Blog Post Two Comment
```

It is ignoring the first blog post and I need it to not post duplicates and post each blog post.

**The code for the api/get_blog():**

```
$query = $this->db->query(
                "SELECT blog.blog_id, blog.dateposted, blog.content, blog.title, blog.published,
                    user.login, user.img,
                    bc.username, bc.comment
                    FROM blog
                    JOIN user
                      ON blog.user_id = user.user_id
                    LEFT JOIN blog_comments bc
                      ON blog.blog_id = bc.blog_id
                    WHERE blog.published = 1
                    ORDER BY blog.blog_id DESC
                    ");

            $data = $query->result_array();

            $result = $this->build_array($data);
```

**Build array function:**

```
foreach ($data as $row) {
        if (!isset($outputArr[$row['blog_id']])) {
          $outputArr[$row['blog_id']] = array();
        }
    $outputArr[$row['blog_id']][] = $row;
}

if(!empty($outputArr)) {
    $result = $outputArr;
}
return $result;
```

**Returns the following Array:**

```
<pre>Array
(
    [37] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [blog_id] => 37
                    [dateposted] => 2014-04-13
                    [content] => <p>blog article two</p>
                    [title] => blog post two
                    [published] => 1
                    [login] => admin
                    [img] => public/img/blog-image.png
                    [username] => Skewled
                    [comment] => blog two comment
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [blog_id] => 37
                    [dateposted] => 2014-04-13
                    [content] => <p>blog article two</p>
                    [title] => blog post two
                    [published] => 1
                    [login] => admin
                    [img] => public/img/blog-image.png
                    [username] => Skewled
                    [comment] => blog two comment
                )

        )

    [36] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [blog_id] => 36
                    [dateposted] => 2014-04-13
                    [content] => <p>blog article one</p>
                    [title] => blog post one
                    [published] => 1
                    [login] => admin
                    [img] => public/img/blog-image.png
                    [username] => Gaddam
                    [comment] => blog post one comment
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [blog_id] => 36
                    [dateposted] => 2014-04-13
                    [content] => <p>blog article one</p>
                    [title] => blog post one
                    [published] => 1
                    [login] => admin
                    [img] => public/img/blog-image.png
                    [username] => Gaddam
                    [comment] => blog post one comment
                )

        )

)
</pre>
```

**Original Array returned from MySQL:**

```
<pre>Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [blog_id] => 37
            [dateposted] => 2014-04-13
            [content] => <p>blog article two</p>
            [title] => blog post two
            [published] => 1
            [login] => admin
            [img] => public/img/blog-image.png
            [username] => Skewled
            [comment] => blog two comment
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [blog_id] => 37
            [dateposted] => 2014-04-13
            [content] => <p>blog article two</p>
            [title] => blog post two
            [published] => 1
            [login] => admin
            [img] => public/img/blog-image.png
            [username] => Skewled
            [comment] => blog two comment
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [blog_id] => 36
            [dateposted] => 2014-04-13
            [content] => <p>blog article one</p>
            [title] => blog post one
            [published] => 1
            [login] => admin
            [img] => public/img/blog-image.png
            [username] => Gaddam
            [comment] => blog post one comment
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [blog_id] => 36
            [dateposted] => 2014-04-13
            [content] => <p>blog article one</p>
            [title] => blog post one
            [published] => 1
            [login] => admin
            [img] => public/img/blog-image.png
            [username] => Gaddam
            [comment] => blog post one comment
        )

)
</pre>
```

**JSON String:**

```
{"37":[{"blog_id":"37","dateposted":"2014-04-13","content":"<p>blog article two<\/p>","title":"blog post two","published":"1","login":"admin","img":"public\/img\/blog-image.png","username":"Tom","comment":"blog post 2 comment 1"},{"blog_id":"37","dateposted":"2014-04-13","content":"<p>blog article two<\/p>","title":"blog post two","published":"1","login":"admin","img":"public\/img\/blog-image.png","username":"Frank","comment":"blog post 2 comment 2"},{"blog_id":"37","dateposted":"2014-04-13","content":"<p>blog article two<\/p>","title":"blog post two","published":"1","login":"admin","img":"public\/img\/blog-image.png","username":"Joey","comment":"blog post 2 comment 3"}],"36":[{"blog_id":"36","dateposted":"2014-04-13","content":"<p>blog article one<\/p>","title":"blog post one","published":"1","login":"admin","img":"public\/img\/blog-image.png","username":"Ted","comment":"blog one comment number one"},{"blog_id":"36","dateposted":"2014-04-13","content":"<p>blog article one<\/p>","title":"blog post one","published":"1","login":"admin","img":"public\/img\/blog-image.png","username":"John","comment":"blog one comment two"},{"blog_id":"36","dateposted":"2014-04-13","content":"<p>blog article one<\/p>","title":"blog post one","published":"1","login":"admin","img":"public\/img\/blog-image.png","username":"Bill","comment":"blog one comment three"}]}
```

**jQuery Function to get work with the JSON string:**

```
var load_blog = function() {
    $.getJSON('api/get_blog', function(data) {
       $.each(data, function() { //Loop through each blog_id section
            var output = '';
                $.each(this, function(){ //Loop through each comment in this blog_id
                    output += Template.blog(this); //output the template
                }); 
            $("#list_blog").html(output);
        });
    });  
};
```

**Template for Blog View:**

```
this.blog = function(obj) {
    var output = '';
    output += '<div class="blog-post" style="margin: 5px;">';
    output += '<h2 class="blog-post-title">';
    output += obj.title + '</h2>';
    output += '<p class="blog-post-meta">';
    output += '<img src="' + obj.img +'">' + ' ' + obj.dateposted + ' by ' + obj[i].login[i] + '</p>';
    output += '<p>' + obj.content + '</p>';
    output += '</div>';
    output += '<span class="options">';
    output += '<a class ="blog_update_display" data-id="' + obj.blog_id + '" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a> Leave Comment ';
    output += '<div class="blog_comment_container" id="blog_comment_container_'+ obj[i].blog_id[i] +'"></div>';
    output += '<div class="hide" id="blog_comment_' + obj.blog_id + '">' + obj[i].comment[i] + '</div>';
    output += '</span>';
    output += '<hr>';
    output += '<span><a class="comment_toggle" data-id="'+ obj.blog_id +'" id="blog_title_' + obj.blog_id + '" href="#">View Comments</a></span> ';
    output += '<div class="hide" id="blog_comment_block_' + obj.blog_id + '">';
    output += '<hr>';
    if (obj.username) {
    output += '<h5 class="users">' + obj.username + ' commented:</h5>';
    output += '<p>' + obj.comment + '</p>';
    } else {
        output += '<p>Be the first to comment!</p>';
    }
    output += '</div>';
    output += '<hr>';
    output += '</div>';
    return output;
};
```

Comment: It looks like your JSON response contains PKs 37 and 36 (posts two and one respectively) so perhaps the issue is in your jQuery? Perhaps add some `alert` statements here to check that it is reading the data correctly?

Comment: @halfer Thank you for the edit, I've added alerts to the function and it gives me the object information so it's passing the object fine.

Comment: Since your JSON response contains both blog posts, it's safe to assume your PHP code is working fine and that the issue is in your jQuery parsing of the data. I would suggest you console.log all the variables you expect to change in the loop to determine the cause

Comment: @shrmn please see the updated EDIT, thanks guys I appreciate the assistance.

Comment: Oh okay now it's clearer what the issue is. Give me a moment

Comment: Try replacing $outputArr[$row['blog_id']][] = $row; with if(!in_array($row, $outputArr[$row['blog_id']])) $outputArr[$row['blog_id']][] = $row; let me know if it works, I'll add it as an answer then

Comment: @shrmn that worked to reduce the number of times each blog post was posted with comments but it won't allow each comment to be displayed properly, it only shows the first comment and nothing more. I apologize for the delay I'm not used to using this site yet.

Comment: Apologies for that, I read your PHP array output and thought it was your blog item output. Turns out its the comments output. Could you post the function code of what Template.blog() does? If it is what you posted in **Template for Blog View:** then that function seems to output the blog post followed by the comments. If you are calling Template.blog() for each comment then it is working as what it is coded to - to output the blog5 post followed by the comments for each comment there is.

Comment: I would suggest calling Template.blog() only once and giving the entire array of comments as an argument. Template.blog() should then loop through each comment in the array to output. Your current Template.blog() seems to only output one comment.

Comment: @shrmn would you be so kind as to show me how I would do that? I'm thinking I can just put a for loop at the comment output and use the object that was passed to template.blog(), but testing I'm getting undefined in console output. Template is the view code for the HTML structure, I was trying to keep everything separated for clarity.

Comment: I can but I'm unsure exactly which block of HTML is meant for your comments. I'll try in pseudo code

Comment: @shrmn this.blog(obj) is the templated HTML code. output += '<span><a class="comment_toggle" data-id="'+ obj.blog_id +'" id="blog_title_' + obj.blog_id + '" href="#">View Comments</a></span> ';
    output += '<div class="hide" id="blog_comment_block_' + obj.blog_id + '">';
    output += '<hr>';
    if (obj.username) {
    output += '<h5 class="users">' + obj.username + ' commented:</h5>';
    output += '<p>' + obj.comment + '</p>';
    } else {
        output += '<p>Be the first to comment!</p>';
    }

Comment: Running into a bit of a block here. Is the build_array output only supposed to contain the comments? Or the blog post itself as well? Your array contents contain two identical arrays per item in the first dimension.

Comment: @shrmn yes that is the problem I've been trying to solve which is why I felt maybe restructuring the array in PHP would make it easier to work on the jQuery side. The build_array is suppose to contain a blog post followed by a new array with the comments for that post. I couldn't figure out how to rebuild the array to achieve those results.

Comment: Could you post the output of the $data array before its processed by build_array?

Comment: @shrmn please see the edit: Original Array returned from MySQL

Comment: Is the original data what you expected? It seems to only have one comment? May I suggest you separate the query to retrieve the blog post and another set of queries to select the comments? It will structure your code more clearly as well

Comment: @shrmn The original data is right, it posts the blog with each comment as a result from the JOIN. I was rebuilding the array to remove the extra blog information so it wouldn't be duplicated in the display. The comments are identical and are posted twice which is why it is displaying 4 total entries. I can create a function to do this in php but on the jQuery side I am lost to append the data for the comments after the Template.blog function is completed.

Comment: Put what I could decipher in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typing everything in a phone is not cool lol give this a try:

```
    var load_blog = function() {
        $.getJSON('api/get_blog', function(data) { 
            $.each(data, function() { 
                //Loop through each blog_id
                $("#list_blog").append( Template.blog(this) ); 
            });
        }); 
    };

    this.blog = function(obj) { 
        var output = '';
        output += '<div class="blog-post" style="margin: 5px;">'; 
        output += '<h2 class="blog-post-title">'; 
        output += obj[0].title + '</h2>'; 
        output += '<p class="blog-post-meta">'; 
        output += '<img src="' + obj[0].img +'">' + ' ' + obj[0].dateposted + ' by ' + obj[0].login + '</p>'; 
        output += '<p>' + obj[0].content + '</p>'; 
        output += '</div>';

        // COMMENTING
        output += '<span class="options">';
        output += '<a class ="blog_update_display" data-id="' + obj[0].blog_id + '" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a> Leave Comment '; 
        output += '<div class="blog_comment_container" id="blog_comment_container_'+ obj[0].blog_id +'"></div>'; 
        output += '</span>';

        // LOOP THROUGH COMMENTS
        for(var i=0;i < obj.length;i++) {
        output += '<div class="hide" id="blog_comment_' + obj[i].blog_id + '">' + obj[i].comment + '</div>';
        output += '<hr>';

        }

    /* NO IDEA WHAT BELOW DOES 
        output += '<span><a class="comment_toggle" data-id="'+ obj[0].blog_id +'" id="blog_title_' + obj[0].blog_id + '" href="#">View Comments</a></span> ';
        output += '<div class="hide" id="blog_comment_block_' + obj[0].blog_id + '">';
        output += '<hr>';
        if (obj[0].username) { 
        output += '<h5 class="users">' + obj[0].username + ' commented:</h5>';
        output += '<p>' + obj[0].comment + '</p>'; 
        } else { 
        output += '<p>Be the first to comment!</p>'; 
        } 
        output += '</div>'; 
        output += '<hr>';
        output += '</div>';
    */
        return output;
    };
```

Comment: This is on track here, it's looping the first comment under each blog for the number of comments in the database, but it's not changing the the data on each iteration, and that's really good for a phone! Also the comment_toggle is just a link that when clicked displays the comments, it just shows or hides the comment div.

Comment: Alright, what else needs to be done? What do you mean its not changing the data on each iteration? Please note its .append not .html in the first chunk of code

Comment: I just noticed the .append, which was ok because I made the alterations based on your post. When the loop is performed it is looping the first comment for the number of comments each blog has, it's not changing the data for the comment. It skips the first comment and post the second comment repeatedly for the total number of comments for the blog_id.

Comment: Can't seem to determine the cause. You should make the comments unique so you can clearly identify which comment is being printed. In the php array and json output they both show that each blog post has 2 identical comments

Comment: I see what you mean, I updated the main post with a new string that changes the values to make it readable.

Comment: I see what was wrong we had to use the var i in the iterations for obj[i].username and obj[i].comment. This is the answer and you helped me work out this problem. Thank you so very much! I just moved the respective functions to where I needed them to be and the whole time it was because I didn't use the correct keys!

Comment: Glad I could help! Good luck with your project! :) @Skewled

Answer (score 0):

You can just use in your model :

```
return json_encode($query->result());
```

And in your JS, without changes in anything :

```
output += obj.title + '</h2>';
```

I don't know why you put obj[i].title[i] in your template function, cause you call this function with an entry, not an array.

Comment: I truncated the function to the relevant part. I actually was messing with the template to see if it functioned with indexes and I forgot to remove them, they were not suppose to remain.. I will fix that sorry.